# How to created elevated form using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a form to collect user info(code below) and could not make the form elevated from background. I tried to apply the background-color for the body and form element but it doesn't look nice. Is there a bootstrap class to make the form area elevated(and also rounded corner)?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<style>
body {background-color: lightgrey;}
form{background-color: white; padding:30px 50px;}
</style>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Test form</h2>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bootstrap allows you to create modals. 1.Put your entire form inside such a modal.  2.Trig modal popup with any event (onload/onclick/etc).

Comment: @svin83 Modal seemed like a solution but didn't work for me as there are multiple form elements in the same page and these forms need to be separated(sorry, I missed to include them in my original question). ex: first form has user contact details and second form has user preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here you go !**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<style>
body {background-color: #ddd;}
form{background-color: white; padding:30px 50px;    border-radius: 15px;box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);}
</style>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Test form</h2>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution. I just apply border-radius on form and change color which is look good

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<style>
body {background-color: #ecbfbf;}
form{background-color: white; padding:30px 50px;    border-radius: 27px;}
</style>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Test form</h2>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```